# Undeclared identifier "isGameCenterAvailable"

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center

Following a book tutorial and seem to run into a snag with the "isGameCenterAvailable" error.

Apparently it is undeclared. Everything else seems to work however so I just need to figure this part out.

Helloworldlayer .m init method

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

GameKitHelper* gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper]; gkHelper.delegate = self;
[gkHelper authenticateLocalPlayer];        


Class gameKitLocalPlayerClass = NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"); bool isLocalPlayerAvailable = (gameKitLocalPlayerClass != nil);
// Test if device is running iOS 4.1 or higher
NSString* reqSysVer = @"4.1";
NSString* currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]; bool isOSVer41 = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer
                                                                                                   options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

isGameCenterAvailable = (isLocalPlayerAvailable && isOSVer41); 

-(void) onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged {
    [delegate onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged]; 
}






-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer {
    GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]; 
    if (localPlayer.authenticated == NO) {

        [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError* error) {
        [self setLastError:error]; }];
    } 
}
```

Gamekit.h

```
  #import "cocos2d.h"
 #import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
 @protocol GameKitHelperProtocol
 -(void) onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged; -(void) onFriendListReceived:   (NSArray*)friends; -(void) onPlayerInfoReceived:(NSArray*)players; @end
 @interface GameKitHelper : NSObject {
   id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate; bool isGameCenterAvailable; NSError* lastError;
}
 @property (nonatomic, retain) id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate;

 @property (nonatomic, readonly) bool isGameCenterAvailable; @property (nonatomic,    readonly) NSError* lastError;
+(GameKitHelper*) sharedGameKitHelper;
 // Player authentication, info
 -(void) authenticateLocalPlayer;
 -(void) getLocalPlayerFriends;
 -(void) getPlayerInfo:(NSArray*)players; 



 @end
```

helloworld layer.h

```
 #import "GameKitHelper.h"


  @interface helloworldlayer : CCLayer <GameKitHelperProtocol>

{



 }
```

gamekithelper. h

```
 #import "cocos2d.h"
  #import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
  @protocol GameKitHelperProtocol
  -(void) onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged; -(void) onFriendListReceived:(NSArray*)friends; -   (void) onPlayerInfoReceived:(NSArray*)players; @end
   @interface GameKitHelper : NSObject {
id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate; bool isGameCenterAvailable; NSError* lastError;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate;

  @property (nonatomic, readonly) bool isGameCenterAvailable; @property (nonatomic,     readonly) NSError* lastError;
  +(GameKitHelper*) sharedGameKitHelper;
 // Player authentication, info
 -(void) authenticateLocalPlayer;
 -(void) getLocalPlayerFriends;
 -(void) getPlayerInfo:(NSArray*)players; 



   @end
```

Comment: Thanks also, have the same problem with undeclared delegate. do i do the same thing except with delegate or is there more to it

Comment: Where do you get the error (which file, which line)?

Comment: hellowolrd .m file and where it says-(void) onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged { [delegate onLocalPlayerAuthenticationChanged]; }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14235/discussion-between-qegal-and-jhon-doe)

Comment: I added some more info to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you never actually declare `isGameCenterAvailable`. To fix this, do this:

```
//HelloWorldLayer.h
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isGameCenterAvailable;

//HelloWorldLayer.m
@synthesize isGameCenterAvailable = _isGameCenterAvailable;
```

**UPDATE:**

To fix the delegate error, try this:

```
//HelloWorldLayer.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<GameKitHelperProtocol> delegate;

//HelloWorldLayer.m
@synthesize delegate;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, i do have a linker error, but ill try to figure it out for my self before asking for help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @JhonDoe - Sure. Feel free to ask about the linker error later if you don't figure it out yourself.